# not able to remove loadable kernel module(LKM) using rmmod

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to write kernel module for ubuntu 12.04 LTS OS.
kernel version is 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
I am able to compile it & load it to kernel.
For loading I use

> sudo insmod nmod_main.ko

Now, If I try to remove it using

> sudo rmmod nmod_main.ko

it gives me bellow error.
**ERROR: Removing 'nmod_main': Device or resource busy**

lsmod gives bellow information:

> Module Size Used by
>
> nmod_main 12394 0 [permanent]

Why this module shows **permanent?**

Bellow is the C-code for this module.

```
/********** Start of code ************/
#define __KERNEL__
#define MODULE
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "init_module() called\n");
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "cleanup_module() called\n");
}
/********** End of code ************/
```

I am getting some compilation warnings as bellow:

> Building with KERNELRELEASE = 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae
>
> CC [M] ../src/nmod_main.o
>
> ../src/nmod_main.c:1:0: warning: "**KERNEL**" redefined [enabled by default]
>
> :0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
>
> ../src/nmod_main.c:2:0: warning: "MODULE" redefined [enabled by default]
>
> :0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
>
> Building modules, stage 2.
>
> Building with KERNELRELEASE = 3.4.0-030400-generic-pae

Please can anybody help me in this regard.

I am using bellow makefile for building this module:

```
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)  

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build 
PWD := $(shell pwd)  

.PHONY: build clean  

build:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules  

clean:
        rm -rf ../src/*.o ../src/*~ core ../src/.depend ../src/.*.cmd ../src/*.ko ../src/*.mod.c 
else  

$(info Building with KERNELRELEASE = ${KERNELRELEASE}) 
obj-m :=    ../src/nmod_main.o  

endi
```

Comment: Please, read compiler messages - do NOT define `__KERNEL__` and `MODULE`.

Comment: agreed, but then how compiler will identify that this is kernel code and also not permanent part of kernel (i.e. Loadable Kernel Module)?

Comment: Any highlights on my first question (rmmod failed)?

Comment: That's a job for kbuild to deal with compiler.

Comment: The only thing that could cause `rmmod` to fail such trivial code is that flags.

Comment: I tried removing __KERNEL__ and MODULE also but no any sucess

Comment: Problem may be related to toolchain. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482469/why-is-this-kernel-module-marked-at-permanent-on-2-6-39

And here http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-April/001498.html

Comment: How do you compile this module?

Comment: @avd, 2nd URL I already tried & it is not working even with setting flag USE_IMMEDIATE. I will check other possibility i.e. tool-chain. & share results.

Comment: This problem is solved. Yes it is problem related to toolchain. I downloaded .deb files to install kernel from url "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/". But I was no sure about the toolchain used to generate these .deb files. So I finally download linux kernel source from "https://www.kernel.org/"->compile & install on my laptop & then compile my module. Problem disappeared. Thanks @avd for providing me valuable clue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. Yes, it is problem related to toolchain. I downloaded .deb files to install Linux Kernel from [url](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/).

But I was not sure about the toolchain used to generate these .deb files. So I finally downloaded Linux kernel source from [url](https://www.kernel.org/), compiled & installed on my laptop. Then compiled my module. Problem disappeared.
 Thanks @avd for providing me valuable clue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add module entry points which will allow kernel to load or unload module.Without module_init and module_exit kernel does'nt know how to unload the module and module became permanent. BUt dont know to fix  i need solution How to remove this permanent module.