# how to resolve module marked permanent in LKM

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, permanent

I have written a simple jiffies code and when I try to do rmmod I get

```
ERROR: Removing 'jiffi_module': Device or resource busy
```

so I did bit of research and found by doing lsmod below symptom of "permanent" being the problem which is caused by exit_function not being found.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
jiffi_module            1027  0 **[permanent]**
```

infact my make file do show me warning related to exit function

Warning when exit function is defined as

```
static void __exit
jif_exit(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry("jif", NULL);
}

warning: data definition has no type or storage class
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘modile_exit’
warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
warning: ‘jif_exit’ defined but not used
```

when I remove the __exit seems it atleast identifies jif_exit - so now the warning I get is

```
warning: data definition has no type or storage class
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘modile_exit’
warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

Reading through below [Why is this kernel module marked at permanent on 2.6.39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482469/why-is-this-kernel-module-marked-at-permanent-on-2-6-39?lq=1)

it talks about gcc mismatch being a problem ? Can someone please help I am not able to debug it further ? Any pointers how to load module properly such that its not permanent?

Comment: Define in as `void __exit jif_exit(void)` and use `module_exit(jif_exit);` macro call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel module is marked as `permanent` (cannot be unloaded) if there is no *exit* function is defined for it.

*exit* function accepts no arguments and return nothing and should be defined either with predefined name

```
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    ...
}
```

or with arbitrary name but registered with `module_exit` macro

```
void <func_name>(void)
{
    ...
}

module_exit(<func_name>);
```

*static*, *__exit* and other attributes for *exit* function are optional.