# USB driver crashes on re-insertion

Tags: android, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, qualcomm

I'm very new to linux device drivers and currently working on USB driver currently. I need to make USB related drivers as loadable modules and remove/re-insert them on will. But I'm facing certain issues.I'm working on Dragonboard 820 based on Qualcomm Snapdragon 820 processor(APQ8096).

> Linux Kernel Version: 3.18.20
>
> Android Version: 6.0

Insertion of drivers work first time.Here is the order of insertion.
insmod dbm.ko
insmod dbm-1_4.ko
insmod dbm-1_5.ko
insmod dwc3.ko
insmod dwc3-msm.ko
insmod dwc3-pci.ko

insmod ehci-hcd.ko
insmod ehci-pci.ko

insmod xhci-hcd.ko

insmod xhci-pci.ko
insmod xhci-plat-hcd.ko

insmod phy-msm-ssusb-qmp.ko
insmod phy-msm-qusb.ko

insmod usb-storage.ko

'lsmod' gives the following output;

`root@msm8996:/system/lib/modules # lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
usb_storage            55391  0
phy_msm_qusb           18820  4 
phy_msm_ssusb_qmp      17033  2 
xhci_plat_hcd           6509  0 
xhci_pci                4916  0 
xhci_hcd              158558  2 xhci_plat_hcd,xhci_pci,[permanent]
ehci_pci                4594  0 
ehci_hcd               69125  1 ehci_pci
dwc3_pci                2890  0 
dwc3_msm               50671  0 
dwc3                  237561  1 dwc3_msm
dbm_1_5                 6526  0 
dbm_1_4                 6197  0 
dbm                     2119  3 dwc3_msm,dbm_1_5,dbm_1_4`

USB works well after insertion.However while trying to remove the drivers (in the reverse order),three drivers -phy_msm_qusb,phy_msm_ssusb_qmp and xhci_hcd aren't removed and re-insertion of other drivers crashes (while re-inserting xhci_plat_hcd). If I do a forced removal of those drivers, it is highly unstable and crashes either at removal of remaining drivers or while re-inserting.
So, if anyone has any input on this - that's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`xhci_hcd` is *permanent* and can not be unloaded with `modprobe`

[Why is this kernel module marked at permanent on 2.6.39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482469/why-is-this-kernel-module-marked-at-permanent-on-2-6-39)

maybe it is similar with `phy_msm_ssusb_qmp` and `phy_msm_qusb` if the *phy* stands for *physical* and means lowest-level firmware used by the USB host controller chips

these three modules are the lowest level that can not be altered. maybe the problem is the ordering in that the other modules are re-inserted because of the dependencies. The '*Used by*' column of the lsmod output in your post says i.e. that `ehci_hcd` is used by `ehci_pci`
However each loaded module is used by an (unknown) process on the system and this is the point why you can not unload the three modules anymore (locked by kernel process)

> For example, in the above sample output, iptable_filter is used by one
>   (unknown) Linux process, while ip_tables module is used by one kernel
>   module called iptable_filter.
>   source: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-check-kernel-module-dependencies-on-linux.html

maybe you have to accept that once loaded they stay and order the change the ordering of re-insertion according to the dependencies

another possibility is that they are buggy, see the case in [Why is this kernel module marked at permanent on 2.6.39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482469/why-is-this-kernel-module-marked-at-permanent-on-2-6-39)

in http://pritambankar.blogspot.de/2012/10/solution-to-problem-of-module-getting.html is a solution for permanent marked modules ( recompile using `-DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO` flag )

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ralf . `xhci_hcd` is shown permanent because it lacks an exit function. If you add one, it is no longer shown permanent and you can remove it. About the other two, you are right they are being used by some unknown processes. I have been informed that these drivers are not meant to be compiled as loadable modules and hence gave up on this approach.